# dynamically populate div with object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

I would like to populate a div with an id of questions with the 4 trivia questions and the answers with a for loop. Unfortunately, as I have it now my code only puts question 4 with it's answers to the div any idea on what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.

```js
$(function() {
  var trivia = [{
    question: "01. What is CSS?",
    answers: ["Casscading Style Sheets", "Carrot steamed soup", "Corruoted style sheets", "Casscading stairs sheets"],
    correctAnswer: 0
  },{
    question: "02. Q2?",
    answers: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
    correctAnswer: 1
  },{
    question: "03. Q3?",
    answers: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
    correctAnswer: 3
  },{
    question: "04. Q4?",
    answers: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
    correctAnswer: 3
  }];

  $("#startButton").on('click', function populate() {
    var testDiv = document.createElement("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < trivia.length; i++) {
      testDiv.innerHTML = '<h3>' + trivia[i].question + '</h3>' + '<div><form><p><input type="radio" name="answer" value="right">' +
      trivia[i].answers[0] + '</p>' +
        '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="2">' + trivia[i].answers[1] + '</p>' +
        '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="3">' + trivia[i].answers[2] + '</p>' +
        '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="4">' + trivia[i].answers[3] + '</p>' +
        '<p></form> </div>';
    }
    var questionsDiv = document.getElementById('questions');
    questionsDiv.appendChild(testDiv);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="questions"></div>

<button id="startButton" type="button">Start</button>
```

Comment: Your problem is caused by a typo; you're overwriting the `innerHTML` on every iteration. Change `testDiv.innerHTML = ...` to `testDiv.innerHTML += ...`

Comment: Change `testDiv.innerHTML = ` to `testDiv.innerHTML += ` and it will show all questions, and not just question no 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

youre overriding your innerHtml in every loop.

```js
$(function() {
  var trivia = [{
    question: "01. What is CSS?",
    answers: ["Casscading Style Sheets", "Carrot steamed soup", "Corruoted style sheets", "Casscading stairs sheets"],
    correctAnswer: 0
  },{
    question: "02. Q2?",
    answers: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
    correctAnswer: 1
  },{
    question: "03. Q3?",
    answers: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
    correctAnswer: 3
  },{
    question: "04. Q4?",
    answers: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
    correctAnswer: 3
  }];

  $("#startButton").on('click', function populate() {
    var testDiv = document.createElement("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < trivia.length; i++) {
      testDiv.innerHTML += '<h3>' + trivia[i].question + '</h3>' + '<div><form><p><input type="radio" name="answer" value="right">' +
      trivia[i].answers[0] + '</p>' +
        '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="2">' + trivia[i].answers[1] + '</p>' +
        '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="3">' + trivia[i].answers[2] + '</p>' +
        '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="4">' + trivia[i].answers[3] + '</p>' +
        '<p></form> </div>';
    }
    var questionsDiv = document.getElementById('questions');
    questionsDiv.appendChild(testDiv);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="questions"></div>

<button id="startButton" type="button">Start</button>
```

Comment: Why do you use `document.createElement` and jQuery at the same time? You could suggest a solution using jQuery to make it more succinct.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to use for loop define the current qustion number out side the click event and increase while executing click event.

```js
$(function() {
  var trivia = [{
    question: "01. What is CSS?",
    answers: ["Casscading Style Sheets", "Carrot steamed soup", "Corruoted style sheets", "Casscading stairs sheets"],
    correctAnswer: 0
  }, {
    question: "02. Q2?",
    answers: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
    correctAnswer: 1
  }, {
    question: "03. Q3?",
    answers: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
    correctAnswer: 3
  }, {
    question: "04. Q4?",
    answers: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
    correctAnswer: 3
  }];

  var currentQuestionNo = 0;

  $("#startButton").on('click', function populate() {
  
    //no more questions 
    if(currentQuestionNo > trivia.length -1){
       return;
    }
    
  
    var testDiv = document.createElement("div");

    testDiv.innerHTML = '<h3>' + trivia[currentQuestionNo].question + '</h3>' + '<div><form><p><input type="radio" name="answer" value="right">' +
      trivia[currentQuestionNo].answers[0] + '</p>' +
      '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="2">' + trivia[currentQuestionNo].answers[1] + '</p>' +
      '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="3">' + trivia[currentQuestionNo].answers[2] + '</p>' +
      '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="4">' + trivia[currentQuestionNo].answers[3] + '</p>' +
      '<p></form> </div>';
    currentQuestionNo++;
    var questionsDiv = document.getElementById('questions');
    questionsDiv.appendChild(testDiv);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="questions"></div>

<button id="startButton" type="button">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jquery like:

```
$(function() {
  var trivia = [{
    question: "01. What is CSS?",
    answers: ["Casscading Style Sheets", "Carrot steamed soup", "Corruoted style sheets", "Casscading stairs sheets"],
    correctAnswer: 0
  },{
    question: "02. Q2?",
    answers: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
    correctAnswer: 1
  },{
    question: "03. Q3?",
    answers: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
    correctAnswer: 3
  },{
    question: "04. Q4?",
    answers: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
    correctAnswer: 3
  }];

  $("#startButton").on('click', function() {
    var testDiv = '<div>';
    for (var i = 0; i < trivia.length; i++) {
      testDiv += '<h3>' + trivia[i].question + '</h3>' + '<div><form><p><input type="radio" name="answer" value="right">' +
      trivia[i].answers[0] + '</p>' +
        '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="2">' + trivia[i].answers[1] + '</p>' +
        '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="3">' + trivia[i].answers[2] + '</p>' +
        '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="4">' + trivia[i].answers[3] + '</p>' +
        '<p></form> </div>';
    }
    testDiv += '</div>';        
    $('#questions').html(testDiv);
  });
});
```